# HTTPClinet.get failing with Access Denied (policy_denied) but HTTParty.get working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
HTTPClient.get("http://xyz.com:port/abc")
```

Gives Access Denied (policy_denied) but

```
HTTParty.get("http://xyz.com:port/abc")
```

Works perfectly

Comment: A bit more context would be really helpful. What are you trying to do? What is your environment?

Comment: @iltempo : thanks for the time. Issue was due to proxy settings in prod environment, have resolved it.